# How to use Spring Cloud Security to do Single Sign-on with Azure AD

Tags: azure, spring-security, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, spring-cloud-security

**Some background context:** We would like to build a centralized security service which orchestrating different authentication servers, such as our own Azure AD, external Azure AD, LDAP, etc. We are using Spring Cloud framework and Azure.

The first step is to build a service which using Azure Graph API to managing our own Azure AD, which we are able to do so.

We are also able to authenticate and authorize single microservice.

Now we are trying to enable oauth2 sso on our microservices with Azure AD. After spent a lot of time on researching, we still couldn't enable sso with Azure AD.

We are using `@EnableOAuth2Sso` and `Oauth2RestTemplate`. It seems like it's not able to do token relay and SSO with Azure AD.

Our questions are :

1. Does Spring Cloud Security do SSO with Azure AD?
2. If so, how? any guidance?
3. If not, instead of using `azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter`, is there a way to do SSO with Azure AD by using Spring Security? SAML?